# How to remote SSH to my home Ubuntu server without public IP's?

Tags: ssh

I tried to look for answers though couldn't find any.
I trying to connect to my home Ubuntu server using SSH from a different LAN (far away).
If someone could tell me a bit about the configuration or point to me the right resources, would definitely appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'without public IPs? Are you on a local area network, or are you 'far away' and must communicate via the internet?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to access my home server from another location, far away. By public IP I mean I don't have one and my ssh connection can't be publicly routed that way.

Comment: I don't know how that is going to work. Let us hope that a real network expert will see your question.

Comment: Maybe this was not the right place to ask. Shame on me, I'll leave it open but will ask on Network Engineering.

Comment: A simple answer: you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way is to sign up for a [DDNS service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS), with that service's application running on your home server.

The DDNS service and application work together to update your public IP address (which means your *router's* IP address) to internet nameservers.

So you use `ssh me@myserver.myDDNSprovider.com`, and the nameserver provides the correct IP address for your router and LAN.

- Several free DDNS services are available. Your favorite search engine will happily point you to several.
- Many consumer routers have DDNS clients built-in, so you needn't install anything on your server. Check your router settings.
- You must still set up *port forwarding* on your router to connect to the server on your LAN.

Comment: That's not enough ;-) Your solution will work if the server HAS a public address but it is dynamic.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's not clear exactly what the OP has, or their comfort level. Maybe they misunderstood what a 'public IP' really is.

Comment: @user535733 Hi, thanks for your answer I'll look into that! and by the way what do you mean with OP? Just curious.

Comment: @tod YOU are the [OP](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+does+OP+mean%3F).

Answer (score 0):

IDK if this will help you or can solve the exact problem in your case, but maybe can help the others, because I was searching for the same problem and found this method somewhere

so, i've tried **Teamviewer**, here is the details

- The server is Ubuntu Server 22.04, I installed the **Teamviewer Host**, you can find it [here](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/linux/) then scroll down to the Teamviewer Host section, the reason why I'm using this is because the page says *"TeamViewer Host is used for 24/7 access to remote computers"*, I'm not sure about the regular version if you asked, I haven't tested it yet, anyway you can follow this article to install and setup https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/4352-install-teamviewer-on-linux-without-graphical-user-interface
- The client is Teamviewer on Windows 11, you can download it [here](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/windows/), then log in using the same account you use on the server (Teamviewer Host), then you should see your server listed under "Computers & Contacts", for more details can see this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVtcD.png)

here are the results when I can connect to my server: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSBLP.png)

Please take note that Teamviewer is free but for **non-commercial and personal use only**, at least for now, for the details or limitations or something else you can find it on their website https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

There is a service called https://ngrok.com/ which allows you to set up temporary tunnels for various protocols. Basically, you'd open an SSH tunnel to the local SSH server on the host you want to connect into; this then exposes the tunnel to the public network. You obviously have to do this when you are connected locally, but after that, remote access should be possible.

Their (brief) instructions for this are at https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with#ssh

Obviously, you have to be careful not to expose services which are not properly secured, or you will be having visitors.